# Deselect Mat Selected Value in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am building an application in which i have used Angular 12 and Angular Material. In this I have a **Material Select** and a **Reset** Button. I need to deselect the selected value from Mat Select on clicking of Reset Button. I tried various things like setting [value] to null and using Reactive forms to set the value to null or empty string. But it doesn't work.

**Below are the code files for better understanding**

**alarm.component.html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="dateFormGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>{{'Filter'| translate}} {{'DATETIME'|translate}}</mat-label>
      <mat-select id="dateTimeSelected" name="dateTimeSelected" formControlName="dateTimeSelected">
        <option value="" disabled>{{'Select'|translate}} {{'DATETIME'|translate}}</option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dateTimeArr" [value]="item" (click)="dateTimeFilter(item)">
          {{item}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-flat-button class="btn commonBtn" (click)="resetFilters()">{{'Reset'|translate}}</button>
  </form>
```

**alarm.component.ts**

```
export class AlarmComponent implements OnInit{
dateFormGroup = new FormGroup({});

constructor(){
    this.dateFormGroup =  new FormGroup({
      dateTimeSelected: new FormControl()
    });
  }
  resetFilters(): any {
    console.log(this.dateFormGroup.value.dateTimeSelected);
    this.dateFormGroup.value.dateTimeSelected = null;
    this.dataSource.filter = '';
    this.todoService.getAlerts(this.currentSensorId).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.tableData = [];
      this.dateTimeArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < response.alertResponses.length; i++) {
        this.tableData.push(response.alertResponses[i]);
        this.dateTimeArr.push(moment(response.alertResponses[i].dated).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        this.dateTimeArr = [...new Set(this.dateTimeArr)];
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Before Clicking Reset Button]

[image: After Selecting Value from Mat Select]

[image: After Clicking Reset Button the value does not get deselect]

**Any solution please ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assign value like this : this.dateFormGroup.value.dateTimeSelected = null

You have to use patchValue or setValue to reset the control value.

```
this.dateFormGroup.controls['dateTimeSelected'].setValue(null);
```